# How do I close this php statement correctly?

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

Im attempting to create a simple list out of some elements I stole from a more complex list of rows etc., I just need list out the values in single row separated by commas.

```
<?php foreach ($document_items as $document_item)
                {
                    if ($document_item->document_id == $document->id)
                            {
                                    if (nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code) > 0)
                                    {
                                    echo nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code);
                                    } 
                            ;}  ?> 
                ;} ?>

                    <?php  } ?>
```

The Result I get follows "3 ;} ?> 3 ;} ?> 4 ;} ?> 3 ;} ?> "

Thanks in advance

Micah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
foreach ($document_items as $document_item)
                {
                    if ($document_item->document_id == $document->id)
                            {
                                    if (nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code) > 0)
                                    {
                                        echo nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code);
                                    } 
                            } 
                } 


?>
```

Fore more detail [PHP Tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 2):

Change the #9, #10, remove #11 line. What you're doing is printing characters: `;}   ?>`
and are syntactically wrong. This is proper:

```
<?php foreach ($document_items as $document_item)
{
    if ($document_item->document_id == $document->id)
    {
        if (nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code) > 0)
        {
            echo nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code);
        } 
    } // here
} // here
?>
```

Also for the "comma separated" part, put required values in a variable and echo it at the end.
Could be like this:

```
<?php
$string = '';
foreach ($document_items as $document_item)
{
    if ($document_item->document_id == $document->id)
    {
        if (nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code) > 0)
        {
            $string .= nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code).',';
        } 
    }
}

echo rtrim($string, ','); // remove the last comma
?>
```

or use a temp array to glue them at the end:

```
<?php
$lines = array();
foreach ($document_items as $document_item)
{
    if ($document_item->document_id == $document->id)
    {
        if (nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code) > 0)
        {
            $lines[] = nbf_common::nb_strlen($document_item->product_code);
        } 
    }
}

echo implode(',', $lines); // bind them with comma
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have all those extra `?>`.  The pattern is:

```
<?php

// PHP code goes here

?>
```

i.e. every `<?php` has a matching `?>`; no more, no less.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Other than the case that @Mihai points out in the comment below...</sub>

Comment: Well actually less is ok if you don't want to send any direct HTML to the browser. It's actually advised to use **<?php class {}**  with no end **?>** for class files, to make sure you don't accidentally send a white space character to the browser. If you did send a space or something calling **header("Location: ".$url)** later in the process would not work "Warning headers already sent". Debugging is hell on those.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: Yes, thanks!  I've now pointed that out in my answer.  But certainly what the OP has is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the php tags you might want to think that you are in an HTML file and you are intrerrupting the HTML flow with

When writing PHP only files (classes, interfaces, traits lists of functions and similar grouping of application code with no templating) it is advisable to open  at the very first character in the file and not end it at all.

When writing template files however it is advisable to use php's [alternate syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
<?php if($x): ?>
<?php elseif($y): ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Instead of the standard:

```
<?php if($x) { ?>
<?php } else if($y) { ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```